# Visual Studio 2012 web console application? (app without graphic UI)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web, console-application

Is in VS something like this? I need to create simple server connected to DB that will organize all data. I plan to use it for mobile app. This app will have its own, native grapic interface, so I don't need any HTML's in my project.

Why am I asking? Because when I create new web project, VS automatically creates some HTML&CSS files, all stuff that browser needs. But I won't use browser, I need siple console that will show some returned data.

Something like in node.js: single, one executable file.

Comment: I think you mean executable file. A file in a suit made me giggle, though

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a *self-hosted* ASP.NET Web API application. Self-hosted means that you are running your own, minimal web server, no IIS required. To accomplish this, take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you're asking.

The easiest way is to start a WebAPI project: http://www.asp.net/web-api. You can basically provide nothing but service "endpoints" for your mobile UI.

The other way is to host your own endpoints in a Console application via the use of, say, a `HttpListener` object. That's setting yourself up for pain though. I would recommend the WebAPI route.

Comment: Typical console application won't be probably good way. I want to create database easily. Non-web project in vs doesn't provide one-click DB creating as I know ;)